# Service worker fetch event not firing (Path issue)

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

So I'm trying to work with service worker in my angular web app to display a custom offline page, The problem I'm running into is

While trying to register the service worker file (service-worker.js) from the root directory ,getting the following error
[image]

But if I put the service-worker.js file in assets folder it works as expected but the fetch wont fire since the service is in assets folder

[image]

My question would be if i have my file in the angular root folder how do import/give the correct path.
so that the scope of the service worker is http://localhost:4200/

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'service-worker';

  ngOnInit(): void{
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/service-worker.js').then((reg)=>{
        console.log(reg);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

location of my service worker file in the below image

[image]

I'm new to angular so any guidance will be helpful ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a configuration section in `angular.json` called `assets`. this section describes what "static" files should be transfered to dist folder along with the application files. by default `"src/favicon.ico"` and `"src/assets"` should be there. also add `path/to/service-worker.js`. and it will reach the resulting built folder